# How To Navigate Images From One Page To Another page in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I Want To Display  One Xaml page Image In Another Xaml Page When clicking On It in windows Phone 7 Application Using Silverlight.Give Sample Code for That One.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Display the Images Dynamically  in windows phone 7 application developement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237215/how-to-display-the-images-dynamically-in-windows-phone-7-application-developemen)

Answer (score 0):

First tell how you are navigating from one page to the other. If u are using NavigationService.Navigate(), we can't pass objects using this architecture.